# How to indicate p-value in Seaborn density plot?

Tags: python, seaborn

[Density Plot from ggplot in r with p-value indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u83fT.jpg)

I want to make a report with a density plot with a line indicating the p value (or any other arbitrary value), something similar to the image shown above.

However I haven't been able to find a way to do this in Python/Seaborn.

Thanks!

Comment: it may be helpful to post some initial code you already tried.